# editing keys and values in a JSONObject Android

Tags: android, json

Hi i have a a JSON Feed passed from a website into a JSON Object what i'm wanting to do is be able to write the JSONObject to a .JSON file retrieve it again and edit values within it for example if the wheres a key of  "color" : "brown". how can i go in change the color to red and then save it to the JSON file again?

so far heres what i have tried but i'm getting stuck at writing the file

in my global Actions i have

```
public final static void writeDataToFile(Context activityContext, String writableString, String fileName){

            FileOutputStream fos=null;
            try {
                fos=activityContext.openFileOutput("/assets/files/"+ fileName, 0);
                fos.write(writableString.getBytes());


            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                 Log.e("CreateFile", e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                 Log.e("CreateFile", e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }

            finally{
                if(fos!=null){
                    try {
                        // drain the stream
                        fos.flush();
                        fos.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

and in my Activity

```
public void apiNetworkCallResponse(){
      Log.v("loginForm", "11111111111");
      Log.v("loginForm", "apiNetworkCallResponse = " + responseJSON);
      String writableString  = responseJSON.toString();
      GlobalActions.writeDataToFile(this, writableString, "mynetwork.json");

  }
```

and heres the error

```
02-15 15:43:59.209: E/AndroidRuntime(7525): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File /assets/files/mynetwork.json contains a path separator
```

Comment: Sure, why wouldn't it be? Have you tried the usual suspects, like JSONObject.put?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that openFileOutput takes a file name, it can't take a full path.  Also, you can't write to assets at all.